# Publish a Silent Post without updating Feed

Tags: posts, feed, publish, feedburner

Is there a way to publish certain posts, silently without updating the feeds and those posts also should not appear in the home page.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Recommendation of plugins or themes or anything such is beyond the scope of this community. Please check http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. Now please edit the question accordingly for seeking help from the community.

Comment: Sure, edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple ways to do it, publish it with a past date. If you need to post content that should not behave like normal posts then you should consider posting it as a page.

Comment: Thanks. Publishing with past date will not appear in home page. Will it bypass feed publishing also?

Comment: yes, RSS is generated based on published date